# How to export Blender materials for use in Element 3D

Tags: texturing, materials, export

I have a model in Blender, which I have applied Blenderkit materials to. I was hoping to export this model and it's materials for use in Element 3D.

I have managed to get my model into Element, but it imports with all white materials. Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no universal language for materials. Each platform uses them differently. and in most of the cases there is no direct translation from one app to the next. Read the following link carefully: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/57541/1853